# How to highlight the elements in a list that match a pattern?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

For example, `{{1,2,3},{1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5}}`with pattern `{1,_,3}`is transformed to `{{Style[1, Red], 2, Style[3, Red]}, {Style[1, Red], 2, Style[3, Red], 
  Style[1, Red], 2, Style[3, Red], 4, 5}}`[image]

Also the pattern could be things like `{2,_,4,_,6}`.

The solutions I can found either require an exact position, or highlight the complete part that matches the pattern (highlights all 1,2,3 in this example).And I have used `Select` to make sure the list contains this pattern.

How can I achieve this?

Update:

Based on Kuba and Jinxed's answer, I wrote the following code:

```
color[seq_, pat_] := 
Module[{i, lst = seq}, i = 1; 
pattlst = 
Prepend[Append[
pat /. (Verbatim[_] :> (ToExpression[
"temp$" <> ToString[i++] <> "_"])), last___], first___];
i = 1; target = 
Prepend[Append[
pat /. (Verbatim[_] :> (ToExpression["temp$" <> ToString[i++]])),
last], first];
target = 
MapAt[Style[#, Red, Bold] &, Position[target, _Integer]][target];
lst //. Evaluate@pattlst :> Evaluate@target]
```

Based on ubpdqn's answer, I wrote:

```
fun[u_, patt_] := 
Module[{p = Flatten@Position[Partition[u, Length[patt], 1], patt], 
rules, res}, 
rules = {x_, #} :> {Style[x, Red, Bold], #} & /@ 
Flatten[(Flatten@Position[patt, _Integer] - 1 + #) & /@ p];
res = MapIndexed[{#1, First@#2} &, u] /. rules;
res[[;; , 1]]]
colorfun[seq_, pat_] := Map[fun[#, pat] &, seq]
```

Not playing well with `BenchmarkPlot`,I used my OEISSearch Package to generate the test data.

[image]
[image]

So it seems that ubpdqn's function is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something different (but ugly):

```
fun[u_] := 
 Module[{p = Flatten@Position[Partition[u, 3, 1], {1, _, 3}], rules, 
   res},
  rules = {x_, #} :> {Style[x, Red, Bold], #} & /@ 
    Flatten[{#, # + 2} & /@ p];
  res = MapIndexed[{#1, First@#2} &, u] /. rules;
  res[[;; , 1]]
  ]
```

So,

```
test = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
fun/@test
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm lazy so this is short but not efficient in general case:

```
lst //. {x___, 1, y_, 3, z___} :> {x, Style[1, Red], y, Style[3, Red], z}
```

[image]

Comment: and identical to my answer, which I gave a minute before. ;)

Comment: @Jinxed I'm sorry, you were 19sec late :)

Answer (score 2):

```
lst//.{a___,1,s_,3,b___}:>{a,Style[1, Red],s,Style[3, Red],b}
```